# How do include config file depending on environment while having eslint not complaining?

Tags: webpack, eslint, webpack-4

given some config in my application, that contains different values per environment. So I have a config for development ('/config/development.js') and another config for production ('/config/production'). I neither want to include both configs into my bundle nor have the development config being checked in to my VCS (done via .gitignore). Yet I still want to be able to access the config in the same way like e.g. import config from 'config';. I am currently doing this as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    // stripped out some stuff
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            config: path.resolve(__dirname, '../ClientApp/config/' + process.env.NODE_ENV),
        },
    },
};
```

It works, but my eslint hicks up at that. I can live with that - yes - but I wonder if there might be an even better solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  resolve: {
    modules: ['dev_config', 'vcs_config', 'node_modules']
  }
```

`dev_config` should not exist in VCS. So `import config from 'config'` will resolve to `dev_config/config.js` on your PC and to `vcs_config/config.js` on others.